# Average Time Duration

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Afternoon All,

I'm pulling my non-existent hair out on this...

Trying to work out the average duration a specific task occurs from start to finish.

Simplified version of table:

| Code | Dstamp | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allocate | 14-SEP-22 10.42.40.530304000 | 1234 |
| Replenish | 14-SEP-22 19.42.40.530304000 | 1234 |
| Allocate | 15-SEP-22 13.36.40.530304000 | 5678 |
| Replenish | 15-SEP-22 18.12.40.530304000 | 5678 |
| Allocate | 16-SEP-22 09.42.40.530304000 | 9101 |
| Replenish | 16-SEP-22 21.42.40.530304000 | 9101 |

I'm pretty new to SQL, so it's probably something really simple - I have a feeling that I would either need to use LAG or Union (or possibly both!) but not sure if I'm overthinking it!

There are a number of different lines in the table with the same ID but these will be ignored under a where clause, so will just be focusing on the Allocate/Replenish rows.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use lead/lag, but you can also use aggregation, which could be conditional to effectively ignore any that only have one of the codes:

```
select id,
  max(case when code = 'Replenish' then dstamp end)
    - min(case when code = 'Allocate' then dstamp end) as diff
from your_table
group by id
```

| ID | DIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | +000000000 09:00:00.000000000 |
| 5678 | +000000000 04:36:00.000000000 |
| 9101 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 |

But you can't directly average an interval. One option is to convert the intervals to the equivalent number of seconds, which you can do with `extract()`, maybe using a CTE to avoid repeating the calculation:

```
with cte (id, diff) as (
  select id,
    max(case when code = 'Replenish' then dstamp end)
      - min(case when code = 'Allocate' then dstamp end)
  from your_table
  group by id
)
select id, diff,
  extract(day from diff) * 86400
    + extract(hour from diff) * 3600
    + extract(minute from diff) * 60
    + extract(second from diff) as diff_seconds
from cte
```

| ID | DIFF | DIFF_SECONDS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | +000000000 09:00:00.000000000 | 32400 |
| 5678 | +000000000 04:36:00.000000000 | 16560 |
| 9101 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 | 43200 |

then average those numbers, and convert that back to an interval (or whatever data type you need):

```
with cte (id, diff) as (
  select id,
    max(case when code = 'Replenish' then dstamp end)
      - min(case when code = 'Allocate' then dstamp end)
  from your_table
  group by id
)
select avg(
  extract(day from diff) * 86400
    + extract(hour from diff) * 3600
    + extract(minute from diff) * 60
    + extract(second from diff)
  ) * interval '1' second as avg_diff
from cte
```

| AVG_DIFF |
| --- |
| +000000000 08:32:00.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6YcePbyZ)

If you have an ID that only has 'Allocate' then that [won't affect the result](https://dbfiddle.uk/v6BbtuYh); and this should work even if you didn't filter out the other code values first.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect - thank you so much!

I have so much to learn....